# Topological properties of $(0,1)\times \{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am having a real hard time solving simple proofs involving open sets. I am confronted with this one:

> Is $(0,1)\times \{0\}$ open? Is it compact? What is its interior?

I know $(0,1)$ is open. But now I am being asked for the product of a line with a point.

Any suggestions on how to prove if the set is open, compact, and its interior?

Comment: What is the topology used?

Comment: Real line, one dimension

Comment: $(0,1)\times \{0\}$ subset of the real line? Sure?

Comment: Yeah, question says $(0,1)×{0} \subset$ R

Comment: In the [standard topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_topology#Definition_and_uses), $(0,1)$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ so [their product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) isn't open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I see, but the fact that I am being asked if it is open in R^1, how can I prove that it is, or isnt, open.

Comment: @Sophie $(0,1)\times\{0\}\not\subset\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I see, thanks. Sorry for silly questions, new to analysis and quite lost.

Comment: @Sophie Just post the statement of the exercise as it is.

Comment: I am ready to bet that the question actually says $(0,1)\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$. Once this point is settled, here is a suggestion: *draw a picture*.

Comment: I looked at the previous year's questions and this one popped up again. You are both right, its 2 dimensional space, not R^1. Please correct me if I am wrong, the cartesian product of (0,1)x{0} is just a half open line from (0,0] to (1,0]? I dont know how the cartesian product affects if the elements of that new set are open or closed or if they form a line.

Comment: @Sophie Which textbook are you using?

Comment: No book in particular, its just a brief warm up in topology. Do you recommend anything for introductory level topology, with plenty of solved examples? And how would the cartesian product look like in 2 dimensional space?

Comment: @Sophie Do you want [metric topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_topology) or [general topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology)? A little information on your level and the courses you took and your goal will help us recommend a book or sequence of books.

Comment: @metacompactness Open times closed might be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for compactness consider the open cover $\{]0,1-\frac{1}{n}[: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.